# Asp MVC ajax dynamic parameters

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

I'm not sure how to phrase this one but here goes nothing.

I have a controller that has two parameters: FindingId, TagId

```
public JsonResult Add(int FindingId, int TagId)
```

I have an Ajax ActionLink to call it:

```
 <%: Ajax.ActionLink( "Add", "Add", "FindingTag", 
    new { FindingId = Model.FindingId }, 
    new AjaxOptions {  
         HttpMethod = "Post"
         })
  %>
```

I then have a dropdownlist of available Tags:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Model.AvailableTags, "Select Option..", new { id = "finding_" + Model.FindingId + "_AvailableTags" } )%>
```

The parameters are populated in the following way:

You can see above that I am filling in the FindingId when the model is being rendered since that will always be the same in this subsection.  This view is being rendered multiple times for different Findings so that FindingId will change per model.

The TagId however should come from the selected value of the DropDownList.

I am not mapping this particular request to a viewmodel to pass in so the dropdownlist is not being bound to a particular property.  I have also created a route for

```
/FindingTag/Add/{FindingId}/{TagId}
```

So here are the questions this has opened and I'm really hoping someone can help me out as this stuff is really knew to me.

1) I found that the href is being rendered as Add?FindingId=## and I was curious if I can force that to render to Add/##

2) Is there an easier way I can get the value from the dropdownlist to append to the href to create the route mentioned above?

Most of the time in the project I have been using jQuery for my ajax calls so I would just manually build a URL from scratch, but I was really hoping to use the MS versions for practice.  Does this seem irrational? Let me know if you have any suggestions or insight..

**Edit:**

I am not sure if this is the way to go about this.  I am finding people saying to use a form and submit that, but if I have this as a subsection of an already strongly-typed partial view, how do I get the values to be sent back in a form I can use that isn't the fullfledged model? I would prefer to keep it to the 2 parameters and not a complex object if possible.